# Are TV Tropes links unwelcome here?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

When I was idly browsing this site, I found something odd: someone, posting a link to TV Tropes, considered it necessary to explicitly warn people that this is a link to TV Tropes:

> You need an [Applied Phlebotinum](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AppliedPhlebotinum) (warning: TV tropes link) to explain why this superpower is real.

[What can give a species superpowers without being magic, evolution or interference from ancient aliens?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/22979/6846)

This begs the question, are TV Tropes links unwelcome here so that one must warn others if their posting such a link, and if it is so, then why?

Comment: It's blocked in my office, I can't read them anyway :(

Comment: @Separatrix I had no idea that TVTropes was such an ubiquitous time waster (assuming that's why it's blocked). Of course I've wasted countless hours on it but I always felt like it was a very culty/nichey site. Your coworkers seem like my kind of people!

Comment: @Cradle2theGabe worldbuilding is a nichey site. And these web filters companies install have shared blacklists with everything not work-related.

Comment: [All The Tropes](https://allthetropes.org/wiki/Main_Page) is an alternate site.

Comment: @celtschk What makes it preferable?

Comment: See [here.](https://allthetropes.org/wiki/All_The_Tropes:Why_Fork_TV_Tropes) Also, note [the second paragraph of this section.](https://allthetropes.org/wiki/All_The_Tropes:Copyrights#Can_I_just_copy_over_stuff_from_TV_Tropes.3F) Also see the comparison on their main site.

Comment: TV tropes? pffft. *Stack Exchange* should come with a warning.

Answer (score 33):

TV Tropes is known Internet-wide as a place where it's quite easy to waste time. Like Wikipedia, each article contains quite a few links to other articles. The thing is, unlike Wikipedia, the other articles tend to have catchy, clickbait-y titles, and when you see them, you want to click on them. And so the cycle goes on, and on, and on, and on.

Thus, you get [the following](https://xkcd.com/609/):

[image]

<sup>See also the bottom of [this page](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TVTropesWillRuinYourLife) (Warning! TV Tropes link).</sup>

A decent amount of people feel obligated to put warnings next to a TV Tropes link, for this reason.

But no, TV Tropes links aren't frowned upon on Stack Exchange, so long as they're relevant to the question or answer and contain information that's useful.

Just click at your own peril. . .

Comment: I want to know if there's a TV Tropes page for the TV Tropes warning. But I'm afraid to check.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh There's the link under the xkcd strip, but I wouldn't recommend clicking on it.

Comment: But note that *no* links can [serve as the substitute for an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/main/tvtropeswillruinyourlife Cheers

Comment: Link to [allthetropes.org](https://allthetropes.org/wiki/Main_Page) instead. Problem solved !

Comment: @Skye Oh, for fuck's sake.  `gpa -= 0.1`